# Enum values() method efficiency

Tags: java, enums

**Is there any inefficiency in calling the values() function of a specific enum class multiple times?**

I have seen instances of existing code where the results of values() are cached for reuse.  Is this useful?

```
public enum Blah {

    private static final Blah [] _myValues = values()

    ...

    public static Blah findBlahFromName(String name) {
        for (Blah blah : _myValues) {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, in this particular situation I tend to use a Guava `ImmutableMap<String,Blah>`, since it's safe to share, can be wrapped, and is a bit simpler to use IMO.

Comment: You can see exactly how these are retrieved [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getEnumConstants%28%29)

Comment: Caching here is known as micro-optimization. Unless it really so happens that an enum has become a bottleneck in your application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a good idea to cache the result of `values()` inside the enum itself if you use it multiple times. That's because, every time you invoke `values()` method, it creates a new array. So, that is really not required, as you are always going to get the same array elements.

As noted in comments, sharing a cached array will not be thread safe, as other thread can modify the indices in the array, as it's mutable. An option is to wrap the elements in a `List<YourEnum>`, and share the list using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

Comment: Though it's *not* okay to share a cached copy of `values()` with someone you don't trust, because arrays in Java are always mutable, and someone could twiddle with the copy of the values.

Comment: Or just use [`Enum.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class, java.lang.String%29) if you know the [`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()) of an enum. I reason the cost of creating a new array is for most code negligible.

Comment: @chrylis option of `Collections.unmodifiableList(..)` wrapper to solve that, though then `for(:)` loop will create iterator, unlike when used with array.

Comment: `EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class)` is probably a lot simpler than most of these alternatives, and uses only constant memory (which you're already paying for with an `Iterator`).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is inefficient, but there's another way to do it that's not nearly as expensive:

```
EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class);
```

EnumSet has special wiring into the JDK to allow it to reuse the underlying array.